# Converting list of elements to string (python)

Tags: list

List of elements:

['1', '2', '2', 3, 6, 6, 3]

How would we convert this to a string such as:

"1223663"

Answer (score 0):

```
list_elements = ['1', '2', '2', 3, 6, 6, 3]

final_string = ''.join(str(element) for element in list_elements)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I was trying to use:
', '.join(str(x) for x in list_of_ints) and it wasnt working.

Comment: glad I helped ! Please mark this question as done then

Comment: @Atul, it is always better to include some description about what your code is doing.